# Eigenvalues for Characteristic polynomial $λ^4=-1$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I supposed that the eigenvalues $λ_1=λ_2=i$ and $λ_3=λ_4=-i$. However looking at the literature, the actual eigenvalues are 
\begin{aligned}
λ_1&=\sqrt 2/2+i\sqrt 2/2, \\ 
λ_2&=\sqrt 2/2-i\sqrt 2/2, \\
λ_3&=-\sqrt 2/2+i\sqrt 2/2, \\
λ_4&=-\sqrt 2/2-i\sqrt 2/2
\end{aligned}
Can someone tell me where did I go wrong and why is the answer above is the correct one? 
Thank you

Comment: You should learn the polar form of complex numbers. It makes stuff like this a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

$$i^4 = i\cdot i \cdot i \cdot i = i^2 \cdot i^2 = (-1)(-1)=1$$

So $i,-i$ are solutions for $\lambda^4 = 1$ rather than $\lambda^4 = -1$.

You can do the same with the other solutions and see that $\lambda^4$ is indeed $-1$.

Comment: Okay I understood my mistake, thank you for that, but how can I derive the actual answer?

Comment: @BasilBassam The standard way to solve this equations is to write $\lambda = e^{2\pi i \theta}$ (polar coordinates) and then $\lambda^4 = e^{2\pi i 4\theta} = -1$ and solve the equations for $\theta$.

Comment: So I have to write it in terms of costheta+isintheta=a and apply De Moivre Theorem , right :) ?

Comment: @BasilBassam Exactly

Answer (score 1):

$$ \lambda ^4=-1 = e^{i\pi}$$

$$\lambda = e^{i(\pi /4 +2k\pi/4)}, k=0,1,2,3 $$ Which give you the eigenvalues.

Comment: This makes so much sense, Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your attention and  understanding.